# my exceptions are getting ignored - can someone help me? discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I got a problem. When i tried to use the try/except statement, i failed. The exceptions are getting ignored. I can block a like i wish to, i can block myself, and the users who are in the Ownerid. the exceptions just get ignored. i dont know what i am doing wrong. using the if statement just failed too, i was getting an error there. so i tried with this one. i'll share my json file too. i would love to see any suggestions or code which can help me.

```
from discord.ext import has_permissions
@commands.command(name='blockuser')
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
@commands.guild_only()
async def blockuser(self, ctx, user: discord.User):
    with open('./bot_config/blocked_users.json', 'r+') as json_file:
        json_dict = json.load(json_file)
        blockedUser = json_dict["blockedUser"]
    try:
        self.bot.blocked_users.append(user.id)
        json_dict["blockedUser"].append(user.id)
        Cogs._json.write_json(json_dict, "blocked_users")
        return
    except:
        if ctx.message.author.id in ctx.message.content:
            await ctx.send(f'You cannot block yourself, {ctx.author.mention}.')
            return
    try:
        self.bot.blocked_users.append(user.id)
        json_dict["blockedUser"].append(user.id)
        Cogs._json.write_json(json_dict, "blocked_users")
        return
    except:
        if user.id in blockedUser:
            await ctx.send(f'The user {user.mention} is already blocked.')
            return
    try:
        self.bot.blocked_users.append(user.id)
        json_dict["blockedUser"].append(user.id)
        Cogs._json.write_json(json_dict, "blocked_users")
        return
    except:
        if ownerid in ctx.message.content:
            await ctx.send(f"The Botowner {botowner} can't be blocked.")
            return
    try:
        if user.id not in json_dict:
            self.bot.blocked_users.append(user.id)
            json_dict["blockedUser"].append(user.id)
            Cogs._json.write_json(json_dict, "blocked_users")
            await ctx.send(f'User was blocked: {user.mention}')
            return
    except:
        await ctx.send("Blocking the User failed. Type either in the id, name or mention the user.")
        return
```

And here is my json file. As you can see, the ID is there twice.

```
{
    "blockedUser": [
        450949112230314014,
        450949112230314014
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your exception are being ignored, because you are ignoring them with your bare try-except clauses

Comment: The try/except clause requires an exception to handle. You're not specifying any type of error to catch

Answer (score 0):

`except:` works only for runtime errors. For example, you could have

```py
name = "Bob"

try:
   newName = int(name)
except ValueError:
    print("Value Error!")
```

As `name` is a string, the `try` fails to convert it to an integer. This triggers a ValueError exception, causing the print statement to work. I'm not sure entirely what your code is trying to do, but it looks like nested conditionals should work just fine.